# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when messaging a valid object

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, ipad-2

My main app controller invokes a subcontroller to handle a certain sequence of screens. The main controller sets itself as a delegate in the subcontroller. When the subcontroller is done doing its stuff, it notifies the delegate. Every now and then, this notification fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

0)Based on gdb, the problem occurs in objc_msgSend. Both registers have a non-zero value.

```
gdb: 0x3367cc98  <+0016>  ldr   r5, [r4, #8]
```

1)I've tried NSZombiesEnabled to track the problem, but I couldn't reproduce it then.
2)I've tried setting a breakpoint just before the problematic command, but again I can't reproduce the issue.

I have no clue what's going on.

This is the delegate property declaration (the parent controller outlives the child):

```
@property (assign) id<ParentControllerDelegate> delegate
```

This is the problematic code:

```
- (void) doStuff {
   if(mode == Done) {
     NSLog(@"Done. Handling back control");//this is the last log displayed by the console
     [self.delegate done: self];
   } else {
     // some controller code
}
```

This is the the code on the delegate side (the delegate has been retained by the App_Delegate, as it is the main controller).

```
- (void) done: (UIViewController *) caller {
   NSLog(@"Taken back control");// this never displays
   [caller.view removeFromSuperview];
   [caller release];
}
```

Some extra info:
The main controller retains the subcontroller.
I've also modified the deallocs in both the main and sub controllers to log when it is called. Based on the visible logs, neither is ever called during the course of the application. Hence both the receiver and the sender of the message are valid objects.

I'm really at loss here. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Have you written your property declaration here correctly? Please, check!

Comment: You essentially have a method that is releasing itself.  This is very bad practice.  The class that contains the instance of this object should be performing the release.  NOT the class itself.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say your property declaration is wrong- try @property (assign) id <ParentControllerDelegate> delegate instead.

Comment: I've corrected the property declaration. I've typed it in incorrectly --- tiredness after a whole day of debugging.

Comment: Do you try to rename method? Also try to print delegate description.

Comment: Try changing the delegate to retain.

Comment: @Chase Henslee could you explain further? The main controller is the class that created the subcontroller, hence it is releasing it. Which other class should have done it?

Comment: @Kevin - with the delegate being retained the problem persists.

Comment: The way your function looks, you pass "self" as a parameter to your function "done".  Inside this function, you call [caller (this is what you set as "self") release].  This could cause MAJOR headaches.  I know this from personal experience =P.  You'll get random crashes much like you're seeing now.  Without knowing more about how your code is laid out, my guess is if you take that [caller release] out, you'll stop crashing.

Comment: @Chase Henslee I'll try that. However, as I pointed out in my question. Based on the logs the [caller release] is never called.@Nekto renaming the method didn't change anything either.

Comment: @Chase: he is passing `self` (the subcontroller) to `done:`, a method of the delegate (the main controller). It is fine for the main controller to release the subcontroller. I see no problem there. He says the `NSLog()` in the `done:` method is never called. That is weird and should be investigated. Perhaps the delegate is not the main controller after all, e.g. not initialized properly? Both objects are valid, but perhaps not properly linked up.

Comment: @Chase just to add one more thing. I've slightly simplified the code for this post. Actually, the main controller has a retain property to store the child controller. When the child controller is created it is autoreleased and assigned as the value of that property. When control comes back to the main controller, the property is being assigned nil value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `NSLog` call in `done:` is never performed, that can only mean that you did not call the main controller's `done:`. That can mean that `self.delegate` is not valid. The objects may be valid and alive, but not the link (`self.delegate`) between them. Check that, please. In `doStuff`, in the "Done" branch, show the address of `self.delegate` with

```
NSLog(@"%p", self.delegate);
```

before you call `done:` and compare that with the address of the main controller.

Comment: I did as you've suggested. Indeed, when the crash occurs the addresses differ. In the test run I did the Main Controllers address was 0x180fe0 but the delegates address was 0x180fe1. However, in the first three iterations they did agree, and only after some time they drifted appart. This is weird, as very is only one place where I set the delegate.

Comment: I further investigated the address problem. The assignment is correct, i.e., after the assignment the address of self.delegate is the same as that of the main controller. However, after the non-Done branch of the doStuff method it changes, always by 1.

Comment: An **address that is off by 1 byte** is truly weird. Something must be writing over the ivar, otherwise I can't explain it.

Comment: Any ideas on what could do that? I haven't got a slightest idea - I don't do any pointer manipulation or manual memmory managment.

Comment: No, sorry. I'd have to see all of your code, and I guess that is not an option. Look at all accesses to any ivar. How are the ivars of the subcontroller layed out?

Comment: Could it be that:`NSLog(@"[%@] Dealocating",[self class]);[super dealloc]` is the problem? I use the [self class] thing to spear myself the burden of adding the logging bit in every subclass. I don't quite understand why this influences the programs behaviour, but I noticed that adding/removing NSLog statement does affect how quickly the EXC_BAD_ACCESS shows up.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. It probably only changes the order of things in the heap, though, and that could mean something (a thread?) is overwriting your heap memory.

Comment: Its a rather simple app, and it uses only a single thread. The reason I placed this conjecture is as follows. I changed my custom code for passing control to subcontrolers to use the "built-in" mechanism for presenting controllers modally. This greatly decreased the frequency of EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. Now, the debuger traces would lead to something in `[super dealloc]`. Once I removed the log statments I was unable to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but if it's "now and then" it's probably `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidUnload` causing the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after receiving memory warning. Check your released/retained/created instance variables in your parent/child controller especially in aforementioned view loading methods.

Comment: The views are created from nib files. I release outlets in the viewDidUnload methods. The only other variables I have, is the delegate in the child view, and a retain property for storing the child controller in the parent. I assume this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform check protocol and method before call as in the code:

```
- (void) doStuff 
{
    if(mode == Done) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Done. Handling back control");//this is the last log displayed by the console
        if ([delegate conformsToProtocol: @protocol(ParentControllerDelegate)])
        {
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(done:)] == YES)
            {
                [delegate performSelector: @selector(done:) withObject: self];            
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
       // some controller code
```

Comment: Simply sending a message calls the crash. It seems every now and then the address stored in the delegate variable differs by 1 from the address of the actual object.